# Convert javascript object of one type into another

Tags: javascript, object

I need to convert a JavaScript object of one type:

```
object1: [{"a":"value1", "b":"value2", "c":"value3"}, {"d":"value4","e":"value5","f":"value6"}]
```

To another type of object:

```
object2 : {"value1":["value1", "value2", "value3"], "value4":["value4","value5","value6"]}
```

I tried to convert it using this function:

```
function toObject(arr) {
   var rv = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      rv[i] = arr[i];
   }
   return rv;
}
```

but I'm getting numerical indexes ([0], [1]) instead of "value1" and "value4". Could you please give me some hint how can I do the conversion from object1 to object2. Thanks.

Comment: There'll be no guaranteed way to determine which key/value pair comes first in each object unless you parse the number out of the `"value_"` strings, or unless you know that the `"a", "b", "c", etc...` keys will always be every three letters in the alphabet.

Comment: ...but then if your values are as consistent as shown, there's really no reason for the original data structure. You'd only need to know how many Objects in the Array, and how many keys in each Object, so you could just as well use `[3,3]` to get your resulting structure.

Comment: I agree with user1689607, if your values are so unique, you may as well just access the values with direct pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is to concatenate the vectors inmates?

Try:

```
function toObject(arr) {
   var rv = {}, k;
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
     for(k in arr[i]){
       rv[k] = arr[i][k];
     }
   }
   return rv;
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for then try this:
**[Fixed (with the help of user *@[user1689607](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689607/user1689607)*)]**

**[edit]**:

`Object.keys` does not work in older browsers. **[Fixed]**

```
function toObject(arr,_sort) {
    //param1 = Object, param2 = (true:sort, false:default)
    var rv = {}, k, firstV = null, keys, obj, tmp, j,
       ObjK = Object.keys ? function(ke){
            return Object.keys(ke);
       } : function(ke){
            var r = [];
            for(var o in ke){
                r[r.length] = o;
            }
            return r;
       };

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        obj = arr[i];
        tmp = [];
        keys = _sort===true ? ObjK(obj).sort() : ObjK(obj);
        tmp = [obj[keys[0]]];
        for (j = 0; j < keys.length; ++j) {
            tmp[tmp.length] = obj[keys[j]];
        }
        rv[obj[keys[0]]] = tmp;
        firstV = null;
    }
    return rv;
}

//sort
console.log(
    toObject([{"a":"value1", "b":"value2", "c":"value3"}, {"d":"value4","e":"value5","f":"value6"}]),
true);

//default
console.log(
    toObject([{"a":"value1", "b":"value2", "c":"value3"}, {"d":"value4","e":"value5","f":"value6"}])
);
```

Comment: The trouble with your `firstV` is that ECMAScript allows an implementation to decide for itself the order of enumeration when using `for-in`. In other words, there's no guaranteed order, so there's no guarantee that the first item in the enumeration will be the one you expect, e.g. `"value1"` and `"value4"`.

Comment: Thanks. That's the hint I was looking for.

Comment: @user1853892: Do you understand that this could randomly fail? The logic is correct except for the issue that I described in my comment above.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: If the object keys are indeed alphabetical, you could overcome this by creating a sorted Array of the object keys, and using that Array in a `for` statement for the iteration.

Comment: @user1689607 I understand (if you read the question carefully - I was asking for a hint not a solution) but all I needed basic idea(hint) not a solution. Based on this idea I will change it to the required one which won't fail.

Comment: @user1689607 I'll try your tip

Comment: @user1853892: What is the required solution that won't fail?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento: Yes, as long as the keys are indeed alphabetical, `Object.keys()` with `.sort()` will work. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WFZt9/

Comment: answer Fixed! Thanks @user1689607 (+1 for you)